# Jenkins Oops Error

Tags: jenkins

we have created CICD pipeline in our jenkins under folder SIT2. which works fine.

But from past somedays, when we click SIT folder for any reviews/editing. it throws an error saying Oops and lot of stack trace error like below:-

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/u01/jenkins/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.651.1.jar!/hudson/model/View/index.jelly:42:43: <st:include> org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/u01/jenkins/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.651.1.jar!/lib/hudson/projectView.jelly:67:24: <d:invokeBody> java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:127)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:735)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:813)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:47)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
```